# ggplot: gradient fill high and low points

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
dtf <- as.data.frame(rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.02))
dtf = as.data.frame(dtf)
dtf = cbind(Obs = rownames(dtf), dtf)
names(dtf)[2] = "random"
head(dtf)

  Obs       random
1   1 -0.011209513
2   2 -0.004603550
3   3  0.031174166
4   4  0.001410168
5   5  0.002585755
6   6  0.034301300
```

Simple point plot:

```
gp = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dtf, aes(x = Obs, y = random))

gp
```

I want to fill the high points with `darkgreen` and low points with `darkred`. The following is not working:

```
gp = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dtf, aes(x = Obs, y = random)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "darkgreen", mid = "blue", high = "darkred")

gp
```

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are structuring your `ggplot` call incorrectly. Why your call is not working is because you have not mapped a color (through `aes()`) to any variable. Try

```
ggplot(dtf, aes(x = Obs, y = random, color = random)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "darkgreen", mid = "blue", high = "darkred")
```

Comment: I have a huge melted dataframe and I will be referring to different variables using `subset`. Also, my plot contains 3+ lines, points plot. That is why I was using that structure. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: @AK88 perhaps you might want to use `aes_()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to map colour to a variable using `aes` and to use `mid`, you need `scale_color_gradient2`.

```
ggplot(dtf, aes(Obs, random)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = random)) + 
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "darkgreen", mid = "blue", high = "darkred")
```

Comment: Time is of no importance, only life.